# Face API "Access denied due to invalid subscription key..."

Tags: c#, api, azure, face

I have already tried with free trial keys associated with two different email addresses and a "Pay as you go" billing. They all returned this same message:

> Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key.

I am using this [FACE API getting started tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/overview)

```
private readonly IFaceServiceClient faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient("39a8b...0fd1");
var faces = await faceServiceClient.DetectAsync(imageFileStream);
```

Comment: Sounds like you've generated a generic API key on your MS account but haven't subscribed it to any particular API endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, Jay. I have an endpoint defined in the Portal "https://eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0" but I don't know how to associated this endpoint with my service calls. What am I missing, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an endpoint defined in the Portal "eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0"; but I don't know how to associated this endpoint with my service calls. What am I missing, please?

If you got the endpoint, you could put it in the constructor of FaceServiceClient. Code below is for your reference.

```
private readonly IFaceServiceClient faceServiceClient = 
    new FaceServiceClient("your_key", "https://eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0");
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That does it. I am just intrigued why Microsoft's tutorial doesn't document that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the URL to "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0" and it works

It seems that the KEYs are not replicated to all locations